# Why does my mail server say it "Could not deliver the message in the time limit specified. #4.4.7"?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, mail-server

I'm trying to send an email to some people on my mailing list, and I got back a few NDRs, saying

> The following recipients cannot be reached:
>
> *email*@aol.com on 11/11/2014 11:37 AM
>
> Could not deliver the message in the time limit specified. Please retry or contact your administrator.
>   <*mailservername* #4.4.7>

I'm using Microsoft Exchange, and so far only aol.com addresses have given me this error, not sure if that's relevant.

I've looked into this issue and it seems like #4.4.7 is caused by the recipient mail server not responding, and so instead of delivering the message, it just kind of times out and dies. Source: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Internet_Email/Email/Email_Clients/Q_20960015.html

Thing is, how can I find out why the other server isn't responding? Is it because the email address doesn't exist? Or some other issue? I've emailed other people on my list with no problems. Some of them are even aol.com address and the emails went through just fine.

Comment: Send to that e-mail from another source like Gmail. If it bounces, you know then know it is a bad e-mail address. Yet another reason not to be impressed with software by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with the AOL mail servers, especially in regards to mailing lists.

Their spam filters are a little touchy.

1. Check your e-mail for structure, EG.

Greetting,

Body of  message.

Salutation

2. It may just have been a numbers thing, AOL accepts xx number of e-mails by a particular IP address before the red flag goes up.

Try sending it the next day all by it self.
If it goes through, take a count of how many AOL e-mails were accepted before the flag was thrown.
Then split your mailing list into smaller daily bursts.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the emails out? Smarthost? Is DNS setup correctly for your mail server? AOL use to offer a web page that you could submit your ip/host name to see if they had it blacklisted.

Comment: I'm really not sure about the Smarthost/DNS settings. How do I check them? And is this the website you were talking about? http://postmaster.aol.com/cgi-bin/plugh/rdns.pl